# Logic circuit for (p ∧ q) → r , how do I draw the if statement

Tags: logic

How do I draw the logic circuit for (p ∧ q) → r ?

I send p and q through and AND gate and get p ∧ q, but what follows next, if I am only allowed to use AND OR and NOT gates.

[image]

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite $p \to q$ as $(\lnot p) \lor q$ for any $p,q$.

So $(p \land q) \to r$ is the same as $\lnot(p \land q) \lor r$. So add a NOT after what you already have and combine that output with $r$ using an OR-gate.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks! I've added another image using your advice, does that seem correct? Would it be incorrect to write (p ∧ q) → r  at the end?

Comment: @AriVictor not if you explain in the comments why the two statements are equivalent (have the same truth table).